# Using US lamps in Europe

Tags: led

I've recently moved to the Netherlands from the US and have researched the use of our lamps here.  In the US, we only used LED lights.  From what I have researched, I can use my lamps here with a power converter or an adapter.  I purchased several adapters and used some US LED bulbs and one worked for a few minutes and stopped working.  The other two seem to be working.  I have more that I have not set up yet.  My question is shall I purchase EU LED bulbs to use with the US lamps and EU adapters?

Comment: Your US bulbs are rated for 110VAC.  Europe uses 230VAC.  Not surprised it stop working.  More surprised it didn't go bang.

Comment: Adapters only handle the mechanical aspects. They do not convert the voltage. You need to use bulbs rated for 230VAC.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest and most reliable conversion is to purchase and install new 230 V bulbs. LED type should be fine.

[image] [image]

*Figure 1. Twin cable with single layer of insulation (left) and European double-insulated cable (right).*

One thing to watch is the quality of cable and fittings in your lamps. I have seen North American lamps with single-insulate cable. This might be OK at 110 V but for 230 V use You will be running at higher than designed voltage and insulation should be rated accordingly. You may need to get an electrician to inspect the lamps and fittings. Since these are portable you can bring them to the electrician and avoid a call-out charge. At worst he may recommend rewiring the lamps with suitable cable.

Answer (score 1):

There are several different kinds of circuits used for LED lamps. There are also different kinds of "adapters". Many combinations of lamps and adapters are NOT compatible. You must do more careful and detailed analysis of how each different lamp is constructed and what kind of converter or adapter is suitable.

Your question is over-simplified and cannot be properly answered as a generic generalization.

Answer (score 0):

What ever is directly connected to mains, should be able to run on 230V.

Now, there are typically two types of lamps:

- Those which provide mains at the sockets. Here, the bulbs themselves need to accept 230V. Though I didn't care about this, I think I've never seen bulbs which accept 110V and 230V.
- Those which need some kind of transformer/convertor. They provide either 12V at the sockets (for halogen bulbs and LED replacements) or a constant current for built-in LEDs. In this case, check the lamp. It is *possible* that it also accepts 230V.

There should always be a label / imprint about the accepted voltage range.
Do never connect made for 110V only to 230V. It could start a fire.